# When using React / Redux, how is dispatching an action that merely changes the Redux state vs actually doing some task?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

For [the official Redux async app](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/), when a user wants to see Reddit topic of "reactjs", "frontend" or "reduxjs", the dispatch merely dispatches an action object:

```
{
  type: SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
  subreddit: 'frontend'
}
```

and then let the `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` to handles the "side effect" of fetching the data.

I would have done it by not dispatching the action, but dispatching a function:

```
dispatch(
    dispatch => {
        fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${topic}.json`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "GOT_DATA",
                    data: data
                })
            });
    }
)
```

I thought my approach is more straight-forward, and if using `componentDidUpdate()` to do the side effect,  won't the component be rendered three time? First for the change of topic, the second time for dispatch of a fetching state (and with the code to fetch the data), and the third time when data comes back.

This approach actually is quite interesting: it is "just to change the state of the app and I won't do anything" to begin with, and then in the class component's lifecycle code (or function component's `useEffect()`), it is, "when the props that come in (from state), says something needs to be done, I will do it, and change more state if needed."

Also, the first way of doing things, if we look at [the source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async/src), has so many states and conditions. This is just a simple example of fetching some Reddit topics. What if there are 7 states and conditions, then the code will be so full of conditions handling of this state is true, and that state is not, and the third state is true, etc?  It can be 2⁷ combinations and the code is so tightly coupled -- if the manager asks some behavior to be changed, it is like the programmer has to re-wire everything and check for all conditions, all actions, all dispatch, etc.  It is like a spaghetti of states and conditions.

I thought the original intention of having this MVC or component way of doing things is so that we have less imperative code, but now we actually may end up with more code (about 275 lines of code), and they imperatively dispatch actions, and reduce, and handle all conditions, and it is even more complicated than if we do it imperatively.

Sure, it shows the "Loading..." status, and can cache the data, and can allow refresh... but even if this is done by imperative code, it may be actually shorter code, and it is more direct and can be more easily understood.

I'd hope to know what methods there can be: do we have to, or in best practice, follow the way in the original example code, or can we do it the second method as above -- is it actually not a good practice to dispatch a function that does async or "side effect" processing?

Comment: `and then let the componentDidUpdate(prevProps) to handles the "side effect" of fetching the data.` Where do you see that in the linked page? I see it using a thunk to do the async work, in a very similar way to your proposed code.

Comment: it does it in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/containers/App.js ... that's a problem with the code too... when it does something or calls some function, I don't even know where to look into

Comment: @NicholasTower yeah, first dispatch an action, and then dispatch a function (not thunk, thunk is the wrapper that returns the function), and then finally update it... the `render()` is actually invoked 3 times (double checked by console.log())

Comment: `thunk is the wrapper that returns the function` that's a thunk creator, but we're just nitpicking. Anyway, now i have a better picture and will work on an answer. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: actually, back in the Algol 1960 community, the function that returns the function is the thunk. The inner function is not a thunk. And the dispatch actually dispatch that inner function. The actionCreator itself is the thunk

Comment: Doesn't surprise me that the term has multiple uses. Did my use of the term confuse you? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Both your approach and theirs involve dispatching a function, to be handled by redux-thunk. The part that makes this a bit more interesting is that there are *two* things that need to be done:

- Immediately update which subreddit is marked as selected (this value is used on app.js line 42)
- Download data for that subreddit

There's a few ways this could be done. Option 1: dispatch an action to update the selected subredit, then separately dispatch an action to do the fetch. Something like:

```
handleChange = (nextSubreddit) => {
  this.props.dispatch(selectSubreddit(nextSubreddit));
  this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextSubreddit));
}
```

This works, but it has a vulnerability. What if i dispatch one, but forget to dispatch the other? Then i'll have the app in an inconsistent state. Perhaps not a big problem if this is the only place in the code where we're doing this, but redux's benefit comes in complicated applications where multiple parts of the application may be interacting with the state, and they need to not mess eachother up. So for a more complicated app i wouldn't want to leave it up to the discipline of the developer to know that dispatching one should always be followed by dispatching another.

Option 2: Put the dispatching of the select action inside the thunk

```
export const fetchPostsIfNeeded = subreddit => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(selectSubreddit(subreddit);
  if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
    return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
  }
}

// ... elsewhere:

handleChange = (nextSubreddit) => {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextSubreddit));
}
```

This approach is an improvement in the sense that now there's a single point of entry, which will make sure both things happen. But it's still actually possible to dispatch `selectSubreddit` on its own. We've made a way to dispatch both at once, but the old way still exists.

Option 3: Use a change in state as the indicator to fetch data.

This is the one in their code. If the state is changed for any reason, the component can see that change and make the appropriate action. This further improves upon option two in terms of making sure that changing the state can't be done in isolation.

One downside of this is that the component needs to be mounted in order to kick off the fetch. That's not often a problem, since if it isn't mounted why would you need the data anyway? But it could be an issue if there are multiple components that want to consume the data, since you may be forced to duplicate the fetching logic in all the components. If that's a concern i'd probably fall back to option 2.

---

One thing i havn't touched on in these possibilities is the number of renders. And that's because it's no different in any of them. Regardless, you're going to have an initial render, then a synchronous render to change the selected subreddit, and then some time later a render to show the resulting data.

Comment: actually right now the code renders the whole App subtree 3 times.  My way could be twice: once for showing "Loading..." and the other to show the data... if depending on how it is wired up, it could show the "Loading..." as a child of App and when it is loading, only re-render that tiny component but not the whole App subtree

Comment: and about "it has a vulnerability. What if i dispatch one, but forget to dispatch the other?"... I mean, you just have to write your code correctly... if you make an Ajax call, but forgot to process the returned data... then it is also a vulnerability? But I guess the code does it "I just change the reddit topic and nothing else", and then "now I see a change of topic and I fetch data and change the state to isFatching and nothing else"... it is an interesting way of programming

Comment: `I mean, you just have to write your code correctly` you, and everyone on your team. Putting code in two places with a comment saying "always call both of these, or it won't work" does not scale well. Better two write the code so that when another developer (including future-deeper-understanding) uses it, the code works by default.

Comment: Actually, I think if this is the convention of the redux store the team uses, then everybody knows: change the topic and together with fetching the data, i.e., dispatch change of topic and dispatch fetch data.